# Booktabs --- unwanted space below \cmidrule

Tags: booktabs

I want to make a table with a horizontal line under Town, above A B C:

I think `\cmidrule{2-4}` should work, but it puts a huge white space under the line.  How can I have more normal spacing?

```
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{tabular}{l c c c c}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Town} \\
    \cmidrule{2-4} \\
    & A & B & C & Total \\
    \midrule
    Adult \\
    Child \\
    \midrule
    Total \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Please copy your posted code into a fresh file, compile it, add the vital missing parts until it compiles, EDIT your question and update your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not have a `\\` after the rule: it does not need to force a new row.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l c c c c}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Town} \\
    \cmidrule{2-4}
    & A & B & C & Total \\
    \midrule
    Adult \\
    Child \\
    \midrule
    Total \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, I knew I was doing something dumb.  Thank you!